# PyPDF2 outdated or not working on Python3, any alternatives?

Tags: python, module, pypdf

I'm trying to run a script using the module *PyPDF2* (Windows) but it looks like its not working or outdated:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Is it actually not working? I already updated pip and installed the module

```
    pip install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in c:\users\desmin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.26.0)
```

If its not working can anyone help me with an alternative to build this piece?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

file_path = '1984.pdf'
pdf = PdfFileReader(file_path)

with open('1984 Note.txt', 'w') as f:
    for page_num in range(pdf.numPages):
        # print('Page : {0}' .format(page_num))
        pageObj = pdf.getPage(page_num)

        try:
            txt = pageObj.extractText()
            print(''.center(100, '-'))
        except:
            pass
        else:
            f.write('Page {0}\n ' .format(page_num+1))
            f.write(''.center(100, '-'))
        f.close()
```

Comment: I am the maintainer of PyPDF2.  It is maintained and got lots' of improvements since April 2022.